# Android: facebook login & logout

Tags: java, android, facebook, authentication, logout

I want to integrate facebook API into my android application.

I use connect, disconnect, share and like functions.

Connection function is called from a login button in an activity HomeActivity

Disconnection function is called from the logout button in an activity setingsActivity

Share and like are used at DetailActivity

Is it possible to use a single class grouping the 3 activities?

This class is declared at the facebook platform

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Well, since facebook developers android integration website is not so helping, you can try
[SimpleFacebook](https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook) library.

I use this because i tierd of the official facebook android examples.
This library is easy to use and you can achive anything with this, you want to do with facebook, it has a nice example project too.

Give it a try.